# Android dynamic fragment loading progress bar visibility won't set

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm using Android fragments to load the code in my application. To create a simple loader I have `LoadingFragment extends Fragment` and then my fragment classes extend that, for example: `MyFragment extends LoadingFragment`.

The `LoadingFragment` has `hideLoader` and `showLoader` which theoretically my subclass Fragment should be able to call in `onCreateView` and `onPostExecute` to show and hide a progress bar in between loads.

Layout wise I have a `main_layout.xml` which has a framelayout for the dynamic fragments and a static relativelayout that houses the progress bar.

At the moment my fragments load and replace from within one another onclick of elements but I have removed that code.

**The Problem**

The issue is the `setVisibilty` in `LoadingFragment` seems to have zero effect when calling it from the subclasses, for example `MyFragment`, why is this?

I have given `LoadingFragment` it's own `View` variable of `viewMaster` which I believe should reference `main_layout` but still the visibility changes seem to have no effect?

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyFragment myFragment = MyFragment.newInstance();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_holder, myFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

**LoadingFragment**

```
public class LoadingFragment extends Fragment {

    View viewMaster;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        viewMaster = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, container, false);

        return viewMaster;
    }

    public void showLoader() {

        viewMaster.findViewById(R.id.fragment_holder).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        viewMaster.findViewById(R.id.loading).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void hideLoader() {

        viewMaster.findViewById(R.id.fragment_holder).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewMaster.findViewById(R.id.loading).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

**MyFragment**

```
public class MyFragment extends LoadingFragment {

    View view;

    public MyFragment() {}

    public static MyFragment newInstance() {
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        super.showLoader();

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lans, container, false);

        MyFragment.ApiCallJob apicalljob = new MyFragment.ApiCallJob();
        apicalljob.execute("a string");

        return view;
    }

    public class ApiCallJob extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String[] params) {
            // do things
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
            // do things
            // tried both to be sure but they should do the same?  
            hideLoader();
            MyFragment.super.hideLoader();
        }
    }

}
```

**main_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="app.stats.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: dont use match_parent inside wrap_content

Comment: "The issue is the setVisibilty in LoadingFragment seems to have zero effect when calling it from the subclasses, for example MyFragment" What does this mean? Can you describe a use case, including the exact steps that a user takes, the desired behavior, and the actual results?

Comment: I also why you are using inheritance at all here? What properties are you sharing between different fragments?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The thinking is having 1 progress bar in the upper main template that can be used be all fragments when they're loading content through api http requests for example. This was the only way I could think to minimise duplicate code.

Comment: @Dan Encapsulation is another technique to minimize duplicate code. Or you can have a single progress bar in the activity's main layout which can be accessed from each fragment.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice that's exactly what I'm trying to do, the `LoadingFragment` class aim is to allow not having to repeat the show/hide code I just can't seem to "contact" the progress bar from within a fragment,  still.

Comment: @Dan "that's exactly what I'm trying to do" I'm confused. What do you mean by this comment? Neither of my suggestions requires inheritance, so "that's" cannot refer to either of them.

Comment: Also, what code are you trying to minimize duplication of? I suggest that you get something to work, even if it has duplicated code. You can refactor the duplication later. This is a common technique, especially in Test Driven Development. Even if you are not actually writing tests first, you can still use the refactoring step to great effect.

Comment: I can put a progess bar in each fragment layout file and control it from within the fragment, it just seems like repeating the same thing over. Having a sort of global progress bar that could be used by anything and just hide the content was my aim.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The issue is the `setVisibility` in `LoadingFragment` seems to have zero effect when calling it from the subclasses, for example `MyFragment`, why is this?

Let's look at what happens when `MyFragment onCreateView` is called:

You call `super` `onCreateView` which is in `LoadingFragment`.  This inflates `main_layout` and returns the inflated view.  Note that *this view is not referenced in `MyFragment`* (i.e. `View mainLayout = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);`)

You just inflated the view that has `loading` view group, then threw it away. However, you did manage to save a reference to that view in the `LoadingFragment` superclass.

Next you inflate `R.layout.fragment_lans` and (after starting your load) you return *that* view as the view to be used in the fragment.

So the thing to observe here is that `LoadingFragment` now has a reference to a view that is nowhere in the fragment's active view hierarchy.

Given that, it's no wonder that `setVisibility` doesn't do anything, because the fragment isn't displaying that view.

I wouldn't use inheritance to do this, but if you must use it, here's how to fix your problem.

1. Let's just use the `ProgressBar` without the view group wrapper. Since it's in a `RelativeLayout`, let's center it.  Then make it `android:visibility="gone"` so it's effectively out of the fragment layout:

   ```
           <ProgressBar
               android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
               style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_centerInParent="true"
               android:visibility="gone"/>
   ```

   You're going to put this progress bar in the layout for every `LoadingFragment` subclass, including `fragment_lans.xml`.  You can use the `<include>` tag to make life easier here.
2. Change the `LoadingFragment` so that a) it doesn't interfere with the inflation of its subclass' layouts and b) it uses the progress bar in the subclass' active view hierarchy:

   ```
   public class LoadingFragment extends Fragment {

       public void showLoader() {

           if (getView() != null) {
              View progressBar = getView().findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
              if (progressBar != null) {
                  progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              }
           }
       }

       public void hideLoader() {

           if (getView() != null) {
              View progressBar = getView().findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
              if (progressBar != null) {
                  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Now you should see what you expect.

---

EDIT

If you *really* want to use the layout scheme you started with, here is my recommendation:

Your activity is inflating `main_layout` that has the progress bar, so I would give some of the responsibility to the activity.

Now, you could just write some code for the fragment that would trawl around the view hierarchy and look for the progress bar.  That wouldn't be my preference.

Here's another approach:

- Create an interface

  ```
  interface ProgressDisplay {

      public void showProgress();

      public void hideProgress();
  }
  ```
- Make the activity implement it

  ```
      public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ProgressDisplay {
  ```

  ...

  ```
      public void showProgress() {
          findViewById(R.id.loading).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }

      public void hideProgress() {
          findViewById(R.id.loading).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
  ```
- Then add the methods to `LoadingFragment` that call the activity:

  ```
      protected void showProgress() {
          if (getActivity() instanceof ProgressDisplay) {
              ((ProgressDisplay) getActivity()).showProgress();
          }
      }

      protected void hideProgress() {
          if (getActivity() instanceof ProgressDisplay) {
              ((ProgressDisplay) getActivity()).hideProgress();
          }
      }
  ```

This way you can take any activity that inflates a layout with your progress view and have it implement `ProgressDisplay` so you can use the `LoadingFragment` class with it.

You could also make a `LoadingActivity` class and subclass that, too.

Comment: Is there anyway I can do it with the progress bar in the top template? Just seems more reusable that way and cuts down on duplicate code?

Comment: this is a great implementation, great job

Answer (score 2):

You calling setVisibility via showLoader on View which is not used to draw on screen becouse you returning other View as fragment view.

Something like that should work (MyFragment):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_holder)

    inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lans, vg, true);

    MyFragment.ApiCallJob apicalljob = new MyFragment.ApiCallJob();
    showLoader();
    apicalljob.execute("a string");


    return v;
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't hide the loader?

Comment: in your xml file set both fragment_holder and loading to be invisible and check if showLoader make loading visible

Comment: maybe your async task is canceled? then you should add hideLoader in onCancelled too

Comment: If I add `android:visibility="invisible"` to `@+id/loading` then it never appears using the above, it's still unaffected.

Comment: check the code carefully , I have ran it and it works as intended.

Add different backgrounds to layouts to see clearly which is added and which is not

Comment: Is that the only change you've made? nothing to the rest of the class or parent class?

Comment: This won't work because `v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_holder)` is null because that's not the layout file.

Comment: In LoadingFragment, you inflate main_layout.xml so in MyFragment calling super.onCreateView will return View which is inflated from: main_layout.xml.   It contains R.id.fragment_holder and it is a ViewGroup then you inflate and attach to it fragment_lans.xml. I do not see your problem, it should work.

Comment: v is not null (it is result of inflation of main_layout.xml) and it contains view with id: fragment_holder

Answer (score 0):

If you are using inheritance then you cant assign layout to parent fragment.

You can take advantage of inheritance for View Binding with butterknife like this and write much clean code.

```
   import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.emerson.techdayapp.R;
import com.emerson.techdayapp.view.activity.MainActivity ;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.Unbinder;

/**
 * Base fragment created to be extended by every fragment in this application. This class provides
 * dependency injection configuration, ButterKnife Android library configuration and some methods
 * common to every fragment.
 */
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    private Unbinder unbinder;

    @BindView(R.id.htab_toolbar)
    Toolbar mToolbar;
    @BindView(R.id.loading_view)
    ProgressBar loadingView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(getFragmentLayout(), container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        //bind view
        injectViews(view);

        //set page title
        setUpToolBar(getPageTitle());

        //add click listeners
        setUpViewEvents();

        //make service call
        fillData();
    }

    /**
     * @return resource if of fragment layout
     */
    protected abstract int getFragmentLayout();

    /**
     * Set toolbar title
     *
     * @return
     */
    protected abstract String getPageTitle();

    /**
     * Add click listeners
     */
    protected abstract void setUpViewEvents();

    /**
     * Make Web serve calls here
     */
    protected abstract void fillData();


    /**
     * Inject View
     *
     * @param view
     */
    private void injectViews(final View view) {
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }


    /**
     * Set up toolbar
     *
     * @param pageTitle
     */
    private void setUpToolBar(String pageTitle) {

        getActivity().setTitle(pageTitle);

        if (mToolbar != null) {
            ((MainActivity ) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

            ((MainActivity ) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()
                    .setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);

            mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //TODO what to do on back press
                }
            });

            mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }

    public void showProgressDialog() {
        if (null != loadingView)
            loadingView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void dismissProgressDialog() {

        if (null != loadingView)
            loadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        unbinder.unbind();
    }
}
```

And then use base fragment like this

```
public class MyFragment extends BaseFragment {

    public MyFragment() {
    }

    public static MyFragment newInstance() {
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getFragmentLayout() {

        //put your frag layout id here
        return R.layout.frag_pulse;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getPageTitle() {

        //Add some title to page
        return "Some Title";
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUpViewEvents() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void fillData() {

        new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                //Show Progress
                showProgressDialog();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);

                //Hide Progress
                dismissProgressDialog();
            }
        };

    }
}
```

**Things to note here are your fragment layout must have one toolbar id `htab_toolbar` and a progress bar with id `loading_view` as this are used by base class**